# street view panorama completely grey

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a street view backbone view. The problem is that when shown, the panorama is completely grey. I am not sure if it has to do with the fact that it is inside a tab and the panorama is rendered when the tab is opened.

I am guessing that it might be an analogous problem that is fixed calling the `resize` event. Is there any similar thing that I could do?

```
App.DetailStreetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085,-122.254775);
    },
    render: function() {
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        this.panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(this.el);
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(this.latLng, 50, this.processSVData);        
    },
    processSVData: function(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            // calculate correct heading for POV
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, this.latLng);
            this.panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
            this.panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch:0,
                zoom:1, 
            });
        }
    },
    refresh: function() {
        this.panorama.setVisible(true);
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.panorama, 'resize');
    }
});
```

EDIT:

I created a JSFiddle that replicates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kNS2L/3/

Comment: Can you post a link to your full, live code so we can debug it? This isn't enough to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, this is the old `display:none` with Maps and Panoramas. It works when I add `setVisible(true)`:

```
  $('button').click(function() {
        $('#pano').show();
    panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Comment: tried with my backbone app but it seems that this is still a problem.. check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kNS2L/6/

Comment: I see you started another question on your second problem. Since my answer answered the first one, do you mind accepting it and then move the discussion of the second problem to your other question?

Comment: if you're using jquery `.show()`, I just noticed the `.setVisible` solution only works if `.show` doesn't have a duration set. Probably because `.show` is fired before the duration has completed and updated the `display:none` style.

Comment: In terms of source of problem, it appears anytime the closeclick to shut off the panorama is toggled, it also defaults setVisible(false).  Drove me crazy for the longest time.